# Can not SET a Value in table using Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'am trying to set values in table, the code run good, i don't got errors, but nothing is done !
I'm using Arcgis10.1, arcpy and Python
This is the code :

```
 import arcpy
 import math
 import arcview
 from arcpy import env


 arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Users/saadiya/Documents/ArcGIS/Default1.gdb"
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

 cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Join_Dataset")
 for row in cur :
     SW = row.getValue("RefName_SW")
     S  = row.getValue("RefName_S")
     SE  = row.getValue("RefName_SE")
     new_s = S
     if (SW != S):
         new_s = new_s+", "+SW
     elif (SE != S):
         new_s = new_s+", "+SE
         row.setValue("Sud", new_s)
         cur.updateRow(row)
         print new_s
```

I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "d:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 102, in updateRow
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.UpdateRow(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session [Join_Dataset]
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the error regarding an edit session, but you are going to want your 'row.setValue("Sud", new_s)' code and beyond to be one less indent in. Currently it will only update if the 'elif' condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to add `cur.updateRow(row)` in the end of the loop, to save changes.

Comment: even if, it doesn't change anything !

Comment: Then check your logic. Maybe the if/elifs are never met.

Comment: No, my logic is right !

Comment: I don't think so. Using elifs, you won't be able to populate both the "Nord" and "Sud" fields for the same row, for example, which I doubt is the intention here. And please add the cur.updateRow(row) line to your code, because it will certainly not work without it.

Comment: Maybe you're right, i changed the code, and this time i get an error ! plz check my questio i edit it.